# stripe.error.AuthenticationError: No API key provided. (HINT: set your API key using "stripe.api_key = <API-KEY>")

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I having issues running the stripe code. The codes are inserted as shown. It gives the error as shown below. stripe.api_key is available but still not working, i get :

stripe.error.AuthenticationError: No API key provided. (HINT: set your API key using "stripe.api_key = "). You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface.  See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.

```
import stripe

posts = Blueprint('posts',__name__)

STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = os.environ.get('STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY')
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY')
stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


"""
posts.config['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY'] = 'pk_test_**********************'
posts.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'] = 'sk_test_**********************'
stripe.api_key = posts.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
"""


@posts.route("/cart", methods=['GET','POST'])
def viewcart():
    stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
        'price': 'prod_******',
        'quantity': 1,
        }],
        mode='payment',
        #success_url='https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        #cancel_url='https://example.com/cancel',

        #success_url=url_for('thanks', _external=True) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancel_url=url_for('posts.viewcart', _external=True),
    )
```

Comment: have you taken a look at the contents of STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY?  are you certain that those environment variables exist?

Comment: yes I have. i even used the key directly but not working

Comment: Sorry,did you mean you used the key directly and it doesn't work, or it works when used directly but when used with the code?

Comment: i tried ``` """
posts.config['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY'] = 'pk_test_**********************'
posts.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'] = 'sk_test_**********************'
stripe.api_key = posts.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
"""  ``` but still not working

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the keys you have are valid?

Comment: I would at least try just doing `stripe.api_key = "sk_test_xxx"` directly to rule things out.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Then you'll need to make sure you have a valid key and you're calling stripe.checkout.Session.create() correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is that you declared `stripe.api_key` like this:

```
stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
```

It should be:

```
stripe.api_key = current_app.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
```

Also, remember to include `from flask import current_app`.